# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined it Titanium

Tags: javascript, json, titanium, titanium-mobile

My response is:

```
  {"todo":[{"todo":"Khaleeq Raza"},{"todo":"Ateeq Raza"}]}
```

My code is:

```
var dataArray = [];
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open("GET", "http://192.168.10.109/read_todo_list.php", true);
client.send();
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
    json = JSON.stringify(client.response); // this converts it into JSON parsable
    var get = console.log(JSON.parse(json));

    for (var i = 0; i < get.length; i++) {
        var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
            title: get[i].todo,
            hasChild: true,
        });
        dataArray.push(row);
    }

    $.tableView.setData(dataArray);
};
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length'.
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: **var get= console.log(JSON.parse(json));**  You cannot assign the get variable to console.log(), it does return anything.  **var get= JSON.parse(json);** is more correct.

Comment: thanks it remove error but creating empty so many rows . But I have only two value in my Json as you can see in my post

Comment: when I  alert(get[i].todo);
then this alert undefined

Comment: Try **alert(get.todo[i])**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to access the entire JSON object as an array.

Try changing this line:

```
for( var i=0; i<get.length; i++){
```

to:

```
for( var i=0; i<get["todo"].length; i++){
```

This should give you access, provided the data source is always available and formatted as such.

Comment: I tried but there is an error of Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'todo' of undefined